# Powershell GUIs (.NET forms), right click event on button

Tags: powershell, .net-framework, gui, forms

How can right click events that occur on a button be captured? I'd like to perform some action when a button receives a right click. Below is a sample form:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,400)
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$button01 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button01.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,100)
$button01.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,100)
$button01.Text = "button01"
$button01.Add_Click({[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Left click")})

$form.Controls.Add($button01)

$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

After reading [some](https://www.sapien.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=6734) [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click(v=vs.110).aspx), I added this below the `$button01.Add_Click` line:

```
$button01_MouseDown=[System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler]{
    $_ = [System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs]
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("$_.Button")
}
```

When I right click on the button, no `MessageBox` appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$button01.Add_MouseUP( {
        if ($_.Button -eq [System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons]::Right ) {
            [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Rigth mouse up")}
        })
```

Or, you can use

```
$button01.Add_MouseDown(....)
```

You can find all supported events of Button class here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button(v=vs.110).aspx

and you can use it in this style:

```
$button01.Add_AutoSizeChanged(....)
$button01.Add_BackColorChanged(....)
$button01.Add_BackgroundImageChanged(....)
........
```

Comment: Have you tried it? It didn't work when I tried it (but my syntax was a bit different).

Comment: Yes, add my code into original script, after $button01.add_click(...) and it will show different message box for left mouse click on button and for right mouse click on button.